# Prepend to filename with find command

Tags: command-line, find, coreutils

Is there a way *with only the find command* to prepend a string to filenames?

So that this:

```
201a.txt
201b.png
...
```

Becomes this:

```
foo_201a.txt
foo_201b.png
...
```

This:

```
find . -name '201*' -execdir mv {} foo_{} \;
```

Does not work because the `{}` part includes the leading `./` in the filename, and therefore tries to write to `foo_./201*`.

If this is not possible with only find, what is the most portable (read: only coreutils, no shell scripts, easiest to understand) way to prepend a string to filenames?

Comment: *"no shell scripts"* . . . are you ruling out for example `-execdir sh -c 'mv "$1" "foo_${1#*/}"' sh {} \;` ?

Comment: @steeldriver only if it is not possible without `sh` and/or coreutils.

Comment: @steeldriver what does the `1#*/` part do?

Comment: does it **have to** be with the find? How about a for loop that executes on every file with said "201*" string? `for f in 201*; do mv $f "foo_$f"; done`

Comment: `${1#*/}` is the value of the first positional parameter with the shortest leading component that matches `*/` removed. AFAIK it's a feature of POSIX `sh` and so should be fairly portable - see for example [2.6.2 Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  But the `rename` command offers a simple solution.

```
$ ls -1
201a.txt
201b.png
$ rename 201 foo_201 201*
$ ls -1
foo_201a.txt
foo_201b.png
$
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
find . -name '201*' -execdir basename {} \; | xargs -I{} mv {} foo_{}
```

`basename` is provided by `coreutils` and since `xargs` is provided by `findutils` it should be at least as portable as `find -execdir` itself.

---

Alternatively, using only POSIX shell features

```
find . -name '201*' -execdir sh -c 'mv "$1" "foo_${1#*/}"' sh {} \;
```

Comment: Your `xargs` solution fails if the file or dir contains: `touch '"*'"    '"` (two spaces).

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with `find` alone, not even with GNU find. GNU find can print files with the command line prefix removed and another prefix put instead, by using `-printf foo_%p` instead of `-print`, but there's nothing similar for `-exec`.

(You could use `find -printf 'mv foo_%p …' | sh`, if you like living dangerously. This only works with “tame” file names and breaks horribly if there are spaces, quotes and other special characters in the file names. So don't do this.)

The standard way to do this (as in a way that works on any POSIX system, and also as in a common way) is to call a shell to do the string manipulation.

```
find . -name '201*' -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$0" "${0%/*}/foo_${0##*/}"' {} \;
```

I don't use `-execdir` because it's a GNU extension and you asked for portability. Note that `{}` is passed to the shell as an argument. Never use `{}` inside the shell code: not only because it isn't portable, but most importantly because it would cause the file name to be interpreted as shell code, which fails if the file name contains special characters.

On modern POSIX systems (anything from the last decade), you can speed this command up a little by batching the shell calls.

```
find . -name '201*' -exec sh -c 'for x do mv -- "$x" "${x%/*}/foo_${x##*/}"; done' sh {} +
```

Alternatively, in ksh, bash or zsh, you can use recursive globbing instead of calling `find`.

```
set -o globstar # ksh only
shopt -s globstar # bash only
for x in **/201*; do
  mv -- "$x" "${x%/*}/foo_${x##*/}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
# Make an annoying dir and a couple of annoying files
mkdir '"*'"  '"
touch '"*'"  '"/201'"*'"  '".txt
touch '"*'"  '"/201'"*'"  '".png

# GNU Parallel deals nicely with annoying files
find . -name '201*' | parallel mv {} {//}/foo_{/}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an asterisk (`*`) instead which strips the `./` part:

```
find * -name '201*' -exec mv {} foo_{} \;
```