# How to run this kind of command from within "find"?

Tags: find, freebsd

I'm using FreeBSD and having difficulty with commands that include {} as part of a string. For example, if renaming the found files. Note that this is an example of the situation. The question itself is about working around the issues of "{}" syntax in general:

```
find . -type f -name 'data*' -execdir mv {} OLD_{} \;
find . -type f -name 'data*' -execdir mv {} archive/{} \;
```

Note that `-execdir` avoids issues with the containing dir path by executing the command from within the containing dir and expanding `{}` to just the filename.

There are two problems:

1. How to correctly quote the args in the `-execdir mv` clause (many files will have spaces or single quotes in their names).
2. How to get the target to substitute the filename at all.

The second problem arises because `{}` for "found item's path" only seems to be expanded if it's surrounded by leading/trailing spaces, which messes up the command args. Example with non-space leading and trailing characters:

```
# /usr/bin/find . -maxdepth 1 -execdir echo "(result):" {}  \;
(result): .
(result): dir 1
(result): dir 2
(result): dir 3

# /usr/bin/find . -maxdepth 1 -execdir echo "(result):"{}  \;
(result):
(result):
(result):
(result):

# /usr/bin/find . -maxdepth 1 -execdir echo {}":(result)" \;
:(result)
:(result)
:(result)
:(result)
```

`man find` states that *" Historic implementations of the -exec and -ok primaries did not replace the string “{}” in the utility name or the utility arguments if it had preceding or following non-whitespace characters.  This version replaces it no matter where in the utility name or arguments it appears"*, but that doesn't seem to be happening.

How can I execute the command I want to run?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358613/prepend-to-filename-with-find-command.

Comment: The purported duplicate does not address either of the questions actually asked, not explaining whether and how to quote nor explaining the discrepancy with the manual.  It answers the question _not_ asked here and which this question actually assumes as a premise.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the last two examples: if `find` doesn't replace the `{}`, then surely it should at least leave it as-is? What version of FreeBSD are you running? And what shell?

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is not reproducible with `find` in FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE when using `/bin/sh` as the shell. I *was* able to reproduce it under both `/bin/csh` and `/bin/tcsh` though.

To correct for this under `csh` and `tcsh`, quote `{}` as `\{\}` or as `'{}'`, or use the below method.

---

To correctly concatenate the current pathname with some other string in                                                    an implementation of `find` that does not expand `{}` properly when using
it as part of a string, one can do this with a child shell.

Example:

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' -exec sh -c 'printf "(result):%s\n" "$@"' sh {} +
```

or, with `echo` (but see "[Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)"),

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' -exec sh -c '
    for name do
        echo "(result):$name"
    done' sh {} +
```

or

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' -execdir sh -c '
    for name do
        mv -- "$name" "OLD_${name##*/}"
    done' sh {} +
```

That is, give the child shell (`sh -c` here) the pathnames as command
line arguments, and then use these in the spawned shell to concatenate
them as you would usually use shell variables.

(the `${name##*/}` above is just to protect against GNU `find` which prepends `./` to the pathnames when using `-execdir`)

Related:

- [Is it possible to use `find -exec sh -c` safely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156008)
- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the reported behaviour on my FreeBSD system, but there are some changes to `find` that post-date it that may have introduced this problem.

Comment: @JdeBP Reproduced under `csh`.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused about the two last examples. Here, if `find` wouldn't replace the `{}`, then one would suppose it would leave it as-is, and the output would be `(result):{}`:

```
# /usr/bin/find . -maxdepth 1 -execdir echo "(result):"{}  \;
(result):
```

Maybe it's your shell that breaks those `foo{}` strings instead?

The `tcsh` I have seems to do just that:

```
$ tcsh -c 'echo foo{}bar '
foobar
$ tcsh -c 'echo foo {} bar '
foo {} bar
```

This was [also mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8647/gnu-find-and-masking-the-for-some-shells-which/8654#comment426212_8654) in the comments on another question about quoting `{}`, [GNU find and masking the {} for some shells - which?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8647/170373) .

Workaround: put quotes around the strings that contain `{}`:

```
$ tcsh -c 'echo "foo{}bar" '
foo{}bar
```

(Another shell that needs quoting for `{}` is `fish`, but it would drop the lone `{}`, too.)

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off using something like:

`find . -type f -name 'data*' -print0 | xargs -0 -I % mv '%' 'OLD_%'`

by using find -print0 | xargs -0, each filename is separated by a null byte, so spaces and other special characters in the filename will not result in the filename being split into two separate arguments.