# "No such file or directory" when using "-exec" with find

Tags: find, cut

I have a bunch of folders which have a subfolder somewhere called 360.

```
find . -name '360' -type d -exec 'echo "{}"' \;
```

output:

```
find: echo "./workspace/6875538616c6/raw/2850cd9cf25b/360": No such file or directory
```

For each found item, I want to do a curl call, and trigger a Jenkins build job.
My problem is that ./ part at the start. I should be able to cut it off like this:

```
find . -name '360' -type d -exec 'echo {} | cut -c 2-' \;
```

But because it starts with a ./ it will just be executed ("No such file or directory").
How can I get the output from find, without the leading `./`?

update:

Here is the whole thing with a jenkins curl call:

```
find reallylongfolderstructure -name '360' -type d -exec 'curl http://user:token@ourdomain.net/jenkins/job/jobname/buildWithParameters?token=ourtoken&parameter={}' \;
```

output

```
08:53:52 find: ‘curl http://user:token@ourdomain/jenkins/job/jobname/buildWithParameters?token=ourtoken&parameter=reallylongfolderstructure/something/lol/360’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Is the error output in the second box what you expected?

Comment: no. I just guessed, it's because of the trailing ./ . What Kusalanada wrote actually helped with the trailing ./, but I'm still getting the same error. No such file or directory

Comment: @Tamás You probably didn't use the code I wrote exactly as I wrote it.  If you show how you trigger the Jenkins build, I could also show how to do that directly from `find`.

Comment: @Kusalananda added example jenkins call to question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You write

> because it starts with a ./ it will just be executed ("No such file or directory").

This isn't what's happening. You have provided a single command to the `find ... -exec` parameter of `echo "{}"`. Note that this is not `echo` and the directory found by `find`; it's a single command that includes a space in its name. The `find` command (quite reasonably) cannot execute a command called `echo "./workspace/6875538616c6/raw/2850cd9cf25b/360"`.

Remove the single quotes around the `-exec` parameter and you may find you don't need any additional changes or workarounds:

```
find . -name '360' -type d -exec echo "{}" \;
```

Similarly here you need to remove the quoting of the entire value passed to `-exec`. But in this case you still need to quote the storage arguments so the shell cannot interpret `&`, etc.

```
find reallylongfolderstructure -name '360' -type d -exec curl 'http://user:token@ourdomain.net/jenkins/job/jobname/buildWithParameters?token=ourtoken&parameter={}' \;
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something similiar and it's not working. `find $WORKSPACE -name "*.mp4" -exec ffmpeg -i {} -qscale:v 1 -vf fps=6 {}_exportedFrame_%d.jpg \;`
   find: ffmpeg: No such file or directory  Maybe you can help me out again :)

Comment: @Tamás you probably don't have the `ffmpeg` program installed. Hence the error message `ffmpeg: No such file or directory`.

Comment: I do have it installed. I just get this error when I execute the shell command from a jenkins(mac build slave) build job. Executing the same command from the terminal works fine.

Comment: @Tamás in that case I suggest you ask a fresh question. Reference this one - or my answer - if it helps provide context.

Comment: All right. Added new question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/495076/find-command-fails-in-jenkins-but-not-in-terminal

Comment: Oh man. Facepalm. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The issue is you are quoting both the utility name and the argument as a single string, which causes `find` to try to execute the whole thing as the name of the command.

Instead use

```
find . -type d -name '360' -exec curl "http://user:token@ourdomain.net/jenkins/job/jobname/buildWithParameters?token=ourtoken&parameter={}" ';'
```

In some older implementations of `find`, `{}` won't be recognized as the pathname that `find` has found when it's concatenated with another string as above, and you would have to use a child shell instead:

With your call to `curl`:

```
find -type d -name '360' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        curl "http://user:token@ourdomain.net/jenkins/job/jobname/buildWithParameters?token=ourtoken&parameter=$pathname"
    done' sh {} +
```

See also:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

---

In `bash`:

```
shopt -s globstar

for pathname in ./**/360/; do
    curl "http://user:token@ourdomain.net/jenkins/job/jobname/buildWithParameters?token=ourtoken&parameter=$pathname"
done
```

The `globstar` shell option makes the `**` glob pattern available. It works like `*`, but matches across slashes in pathnames.

Comment: Minor quibble: Some `find` releases, not some shells.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Well OK, I'll add that (as soon as I get to a computer). The csh shell will mess up if concatenating {} with a string, and that's the only current issue that I've seen anyone have recently. That's why I only mentioned shells.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/453198/116858

Comment: That's an issue in tcsh only without adequate quoting (AIUI, csh not my strength); with the quotes in your code it'd be fine. Re: the `find` end of things, quoting from [the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html): *If a utility_name or argument string contains the two characters "{}", but not just the two characters "{}", it is implementation-defined whether find replaces those two characters or uses the string without change.*

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You're right. With the quotes it'll be alright.