# Error using exec in find command

Tags: bash, shell, find, command

To remove all emails for all users of a Linux machine, I run:

```
find /var/spool/mail/ -regextype sed -regex "^.*[^/]$" -exec :> {} \;
```

... however I received the following error message(s):

```
find: ‘:’: No such file or directory
find: ‘:’: No such file or directory
find: ‘:’: No such file or directory
```

What is wrong?

Comment: But your attempt wouldn't work anyway, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/481707/70524. Try `truncate`, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks, @muru. Indeed, `find /var/spool/mail/ -regextype sed -regex "^.*[^/]$" -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;` is the best solution.

Comment: @muru It's IMHO not an exact duplicate as the built-in-ness of `:` is only part of the issue. The redirection is the other part.

Comment: Note that even if this worked, you wouldn't need the `:` in the first place (not in bash, anyway). You can just do `> file` and that will empty it. There's no need to do `: > file`. So even less of a duplicate since the `:` is essentially irrelevant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want to truncate the mailboxes for all users.  You can't do this by calling `:` from `find` as `:` is not an external utility (it's a shell built-in utility).  Using `true` instead of `:` would have worked since that is commonly available as an external command, but...

You also can't use a redirection in the command executed via `-exec` since that redirection would be acted upon by the shell at the time when the `find` utility first starts (not once for each found file).

Your command is essentially the same as

```
find /var/spool/mail/ -regextype sed -regex "^.*[^/]$" -exec : \; >{}
```

i.e., it will create a file called `{}` into which the standard output stream of `find` is redirected.

Instead, you may do something like

```
find /var/spool/mail -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        : >"$pathname"
    done' sh {} +
```

As a "one-liner":

```
find /var/spool/mail -type f -exec sh -c 'for pathname do : >"$pathname"; done' sh {} +
```

Or, if all mailboxes are immediately beneath `/var/spool/mail`,

```
for pathname in /var/spool/mail/*; do
    : >"$pathname"
done
```

As a "one-liner":

```
for pathname in /var/spool/mail/*; do : >"$pathname"; done
```

In both of these variations, the `:` utility is correctly invoked and the redirection will happen for each found pathname (any regular file in or below the given search path).

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: What's the point of the `:` anyway? Why not just `> "$pathname"`? Does the `:` add anything useful? Is `> file` not enough on some systems?

Comment: @terdon That depends a bit on the shell. In `zsh`, that would be equivalent of `cat >"$pathname"` and would therefore wait for input. Using `:` with a redirection is therefore more portable than a "naked" redirection. I also kept the use of `:` instead of using e.g. `true` as this was what was used in the question.  Also, since the redirection was another issue, you might as well keep using `:` (as I did) as it's guaranteed to be a built-in utility.

Comment: @terdon As for GNU `truncate`, it's non-standard and I don't have it on my system.

Comment: Nah, the point about zsh had me covered already, thanks. I had assumed that the redirection handling was POSIX and all shells would handle `> file` as a command to empty a file. First time I've seen a case where bash was saner than zsh (for my taste, at least)!

Answer (score 4):

What's the point of using a regex here?  Why not just use `find /var/spool/mail/ -type f`?  and use `-maxdepth 1` if you want to prevent recursion into any sub-directories.

Also, why truncate the user mailboxes when you can just delete them?  e.g.

```
find /var/spool/mail/ -type f -delete
```

or

```
find /var/spool/mail/ -type f -exec rm {} +
```

When new mail arrives for a user, the MTA or MDA will create the mbox files as required, with the correct ownership and perms.