# Windows PowerShell command resulting in unexpected behaviour

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

This looks more complicated than it needs to be, as it's the result of me trying to see what was happening. It was initially all in the `find -exec` command.

This is in Linux on Windows WSL, where I am trying to execute a PowerShell script in every subdirectory of the directories in the array. after converting the paths in to Windows format.

```
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
  dirlist=$(mktemp)
  find "$dir" -name '.?*' -prune -o -type d -print -exec printf "%s\n" {} >>${dirlist} \;
  while read p; do
    windir="$(wslpath -w "$p")"
    echo "$windir"
    powershell.exe -File F:\\Path\\to\\script.ps1 "$windir"
  done <"${dirlist}"
done
```

Only the top-level directories (which are in the array) have the PowerShell script execute in them and only they are printed (correctly in Windows format) by the `echo` command.

But when I comment-out the `powershell.exe` line, all the subdirectories are printed by the `echo` command.

Why is that happening?

Comment: I'll be honest: this sound like this script should be a powershell script, not a bash script,.

Comment: you `-print` and you also `-exec printf …`. Shouldn't that by design lead to everything being printed twice?

Comment: Also, not sure what `p` is here!

Comment: Your find command definitely isn't doing what you think it does https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/481707/70524

Comment: You're invoking `dirlist=$(mktemp)` multiple times - creating a new `$dirlist` file for each each element of the `$dirs` array.  Since your `find` command appends to the `$dirlist` file, I suspect you actually want a single master `$dirlist` file.  Move the line `dirlist=$(mktemp) `to before the `for dir in ...` line (outside the loop)

Comment: @muru: The find command just gets all directories which are not (Linux) hidden. As the result is a single string to one value and am doing the intermediate file convolution, but the thing I am confused about is what I mention in the question.

Comment: @SottoVoce the reason I used intermediate files is because the `find` command was coming out with a single string the `\n` newlines.

Comment: @MarcusMüller That is probably true. I just thought that this would be quicker than learning PowerShell, but I may be changing my mind about that.

Comment: Don't you just want `find "$dir" -type d -not -name '.*'`? Or even, avoiding the loop, `find "${dirs[@]}" -mindepth 1 -type d -not -name '.*'`?

Comment: @paradroid the result is the file with all paths duplicated, because the redirection that you think you're doing in the `-exec` is actually being done by the parent shell, so redirecting the entrie output of `find`